# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined - React Redux Toolkit Testing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, typeerror, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

In my React project I'm using redux toolkit and all is working fine on the UI side, but I'm running into the following error now I've come to testing my code (Note - I have chosen RTL as my library of choice, and I know I should test as I write code but I'm here now anyway).

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSearching' of undefined

      16 |   const postState = useSelector(selectInitialPostsState);
    > 17 |   const isSearching = postState.isSearching;
```

As can be seen above, I import my initialState and save it to postState in my component, and then access isSearching from there - which works absolutely fine in my code and my App. I have accessed my state properties this way throughout my code as it seemed easier than having to write an individual selector for each state property used.

In my test file, I have resorted to Redux's test writing docs and have tried two different ways of rendering my store via manipulating RTL's render() method. The first function written locally in my test file, which for the time being I have commented out, and the second is imported into my test file from test-utils. Both methods give me the same errors.

Here is my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
// import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// import { render as rtlRender, screen, fireEvent, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';  
// import { store } from '../../app/store';

import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '../../../utilities/test-utils';
import Header from '../Header';

// const render = component => rtlRender(
//   <Provider store={store}>   
//     {component}
//   </Provider>
// );

describe('Header Component', () => {  
  // let component;
  // beforeEach(() => {
  //   component = render(<Header />)
  // });

  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    render(<Header />);
    // expect(screen.getByText('Reddit')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

And here is my test-utils file:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 
// Import your own reducer
import sideNavReducer from '../src/features/sideNavSlice';
import postReducer from '../src/features/postSlice'; 

function render(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState,
    store = configureStore({ reducer: { sideNav: sideNavReducer, posts: postReducer }, preloadedState }),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return ( 
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
//override render method
export { render }
```

I have been able to prevent this error by creating a selector that saves the property directly, and accessing it in my component as *isSearching* without having to use *postState.isSearching*, but then the next error comes up about the next property I have to do this with, and then the next and so on.

It seems that in my test file, postState is undefined, whereas in my console, it holds the initialState from my slice file. Can anyone please advise why this is? I don't see a reason why I would have to write numerous selectors that directly access properties, rather than accessing them through an initialState selector. I can't seem to grasp how it works in my functioning code but not in my test code.

For further context if required, here is the mentioned initialState and selector from my slice file:

```
const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'posts', 
  initialState: {
    allPosts: [], 
    popularPosts: [],
    sportPosts: [],
    newsPosts: [],
    savedPosts: [],
    hiddenPosts: [],
    reportedPosts: [],
    dataLoading: true, 
    allPostsShown: true,
    ellipsisClicked: false, 
    reportModal: false,
    modalClosed: true,
    imgClicked: false,
    searchedPostsFound: false,
    searchedPosts: [],
    isSearching: false,
    searchText: "",
  },
});

export const selectInitialPostsState = state => state.posts;
```

And here is how it is used in my component. I have only included the relevant code.

```
const SideNav = () => {
 const postState = useSelector(selectInitialPostsState);
 const isSearching = postState.isSearching; 

 useEffect(() => {
    !isSearching && setSearchText(""); 
    if(!searchText){
      dispatch(userNoSearch());
      dispatch(searchedPostsFound({ ids: undefined, text: searchText }));   // reset searchedPosts state array 
    }
  }, [dispatch, searchText, isSearching]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isSearching){
      dispatch(searchedPostsFound());
    }
  }, [dispatch, isSearching, search]);
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store or any other mock fir your redux store ?

Comment: @FlorianMotteau I have had a look at it but it centres more around dispatching actions, and whilst I know I will eventually have to do this I was looking to begin with simple tests such as the ones shown above. I'm not sure how I'd use redux-mock-store to render my component so that I can perform assertions on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the initialState of your component, you need to send it as a parameter to `rtlRender` with your component.

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  rtlRender(<Header />, { preloadedState: mockStateHere });
  // expect(screen.getByText('Reddit')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

your `mockStateHere` structure needs to resemble what your redux store's state looks like as best as possible, using `entities` and `id`'s etc

If you look at how you are building the `render` function in this example, you'll see the param `preloadedState` being deconstructed along with `store` which has the default configuration in this example:

```
function render(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState,
    store = configureStore({ reducer: { sideNav: sideNavReducer, posts: postReducer }, preloadedState }),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
...
)
```

that's the same `preloadedState` value that you send in with your `ui` component, which is being loaded into your store with the `configureStore` method and that store value will be sent into the `Provider`

Comment: I did end up using the mutated rtlRender, and solved the questioned errors by changing all my selectors to direct selectors of the specific state, but then ran into issues when using .map() to render an array in my state, it was undefined. To resolve this I had to use const filters = useSelector(selectPostFiltersArr) || [];. However my test file now renders an empty array which I know by using screen.debug(). I have just attempted to use the preloadedState parameter followed by my state as you advised, but it still isn't rendering the array in .debug(). What do you advise? @DevAchievem

Comment: What does your `preloadedState` look like now compared to your `initialState`? 
And when you are running your tests what does `state` look like in your header?  I have been finding it useful for my own testing with RTK to open some curly brackets in my `useSelector` hook to run some `console.log`'s in there like this: 
`const postState = useSelector((state) => {  console.log(state)  return selectInitialPostsState()});` << sorry this shouldn't be a one-liner I believe but alas it's just a comment. This has helped me match my mockState and confirm it exists in there before moving forward :)

Comment: Using `const filters = useSelector((state) => { console.log(state) return selectPostFiltersArr });`, full state and the path to my postFiltersArr, `state => state.posts.postFiltersArr` are logged to console. In my test, I have set the preloadedState, `render(<PostFilters />, { preloadedState: { 'posts': { postFiltersArr: [ { filter: 'All', checked: false, posts: 0 } ] }}});` but with all 7 of my different filter objects in the array as is in my postSlice state. It mimics the consoled path, state.posts.postFiltersArr, but still doesn't render them in my test file.  @DevAchievem